# Как отредактировать страницу при проксировании через Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy

Мне необходимо дописать в блок дополнительный атрибут после проксирования страницы перед загрузкой ее браузером. Сервер на Node.js В гугле нашел такой способ проксирования страницы на Node.js:

```
var http = require('http')
var url = require('url')
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    console.log(request.url)
    var ph = url.parse(request.url)
    var options = {
        port: ph.port,
        hostname: ph.hostname,
        method: request.method,
        path: ph.path,
        headers: request.headers
    }
    var proxyRequest = http.request(options)
    proxyRequest.on('response', function(proxyResponse) {
        proxyResponse.on('data', function(chunk) {
            response.write(chunk, 'binary')
        })
        proxyResponse.on('end', function() { response.end() })
        response.writeHead(proxyResponse.statusCode, proxyResponse.headers)
    })
    request.on('data', function(chunk) {
        proxyRequest.write(chunk, 'binary')
    })
    request.on('end', function() { proxyRequest.end() })
}).listen(8080)
```

Можно ли с помощью этого способа на каком-то этапе получить html-код получаемой страницы, внести в него корректировку и отправить на загрузку в браузер отредактированную версию?

Comment: Прокси лучше на nginx делать. И там также можно [менять на лету контент](https://serverfault.com/questions/713148/modify-html-pages-returned-by-nginx-reverse-proxy)

Comment: @TotalPusher спасибо за совет. Покопаю в этом направлении.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Суть этого скрипта - получаем данные в буффер, производим замену и отдаем назад. Самая большая проблема для меня была кодировка. Вот рабочий пример:

```
"use strict";

const
  http = require('http'),
  url = require('url'),
  // для установки этого модуля выполнить: npm i -S iconv
  Iconv  = require('iconv').Iconv
  ;

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {

    var ph = url.parse(request.url);

    var options = {
      port: ph.port ? parseInt(ph.port) : 80,
      hostname: ph.hostname,
      method: request.method,
      path: ph.path,
      headers: request.headers
    }

    var proxyRequest = http.request(options)

    proxyRequest.on('response', function(proxyResponse) {
      // буффер с телом ответа
      var buf = Buffer.alloc(0, 'binary');

      proxyResponse.on('data', function(chunk) {
        // собираем тело ответа по частям (без заголовоков, только тело)
        buf = Buffer.concat([buf, chunk]);
      });

      proxyResponse.on('end', function() {
        // по-умолчанию будем считать кодировку буфера текста latin-1, она же binary
        var headCharset = 'latin1';

        // если в заголовках указана кодировка, используем ее
        var _m = proxyResponse.headers['content-type'].match(/charset=(.+)/i);
        if(_m) {
          headCharset = _m[1].toLowerCase();
        }

        // превращаем бинарный буфер в строку utf-8 (внутренняя кодировка JavaScript) согласно определенной кодировки
        var iconv = new Iconv(headCharset, 'utf-8');
        buf = iconv.convert(buf);
        var body = buf.toString('utf-8');

        // Производим замену
        // Правильное определение кодировки очень важно, иначе символы, не входящие в latin-1, не будут заменены
        body = body.replace(/hello/gi, '-');
        body = body.replace(/привет/gi, '-');

        // Конвертируем назад в ту кодировку, которая была
        iconv = new Iconv('utf-8', headCharset);
        buf = Buffer.from(body, 'utf-8');
        buf = iconv.convert(buf);


        // Меняем длину 'content-length', иначе клиент будет ругаться:
        // curl: (18) transfer closed with 12 bytes remaining to read
        proxyResponse.headers['content-length'] = buf.length;

        // отправляем заголовки
        response.writeHead(proxyResponse.statusCode, proxyResponse.headers);

        // отправляем тело
        response.write(buf, 'binary');

        // конец передачи
        response.end();
      });

    });

    request.on('data', function(chunk) {
        proxyRequest.write(chunk, 'binary')
    });

    request.on('end', function() { proxyRequest.end() });

}).listen(8080);
```

Как проверить из bash:

```
export http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8080
curl http://site.ru/cp1251/
curl http://site.ru/utf-8/
```

Comment: Не удается установить Iconv. "Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable." Я правильно понимаю, что нужно установить переменную среды PYTHON? Я питон в руках в жизни не держал и не знаю этого языка. Без него здесь можно обойтись? Или речь не о языке?

Comment: `npm init` (если еще не делали) затем `npm i -S iconv`, правильно? Питон тут при том, что используется `node-gyp`. Что говорит `which python`?

Comment: Да, `npm inin` делал, команда на установку верная, да. Что такое `which python` и где он должен что говорить? В логе ошибок я такой строки не нашел.

Comment: как система? это команда linux для простой проверки "где питон?". Ее надо вводить в консоль. Думаю, вам нужно ставить питон. Он сам по себе не нужен, но с пакетами npm есть такая штука - может понадобиться все что угодно